# how can I always have two decimals in my label and align the price list

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am implementing an ionic mobile app. in the typescript class of my component I have an array of numbers (prices). some are whole numbers and some are with two decimal places. I want to display this in the component as a column of price list. For this I am using  with alignment set to right. For the price list to align properly, I need to display the whole numbers with two zero decimals. How can I do this

type script

```
price1 = 21.23;
price2 = 20;
```

in html in ionic component

```
<ion-grid>
    <on-row>
      <ion-col>
         <ion-label class="ion-text-end">{{price1}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </on-row>
    <on-row>
      <ion-col>
         <ion-label class="ion-text-end">{{price2}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </on-row>

</ion-grid>
```

I want it aligned as,

```
21.23
20.00
```

But it's not. Not even the text get aligned to the right.

Can someone advise how I can achieve this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DecimalPipe`, like this:

```
{{ price2 | number : '1.2-2'}}
```

You can check more in the doc:
https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

And also in Angular Wiki:
https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-decimal-pipe/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

- Move `ion-text-end` class to `ion-col` (because `ion-label` display is inline)
- Use number pipe for formatting numbers
- Since it's price, I'd recommend using currency pipe (currency pipe use two-decimals as default)

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-end">
         <ion-label >{{price1 | number: '1.2-2'}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </on-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-end">
         <ion-label >{{price2 | currency:'USD':'symbol' }}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```